# Javascript length of a div says undefined

Tags: javascript, division

I have a div with id `user`. When I check it's length it says undefined even when it exists.

```
<div id="user"></div>
```

I use pure javascript like below.

```
var user = document.getElementById("user").length;
console.log(user);
```

Any idea how to check the length without using jQuery?

Comment: What is a div's length?

Comment: But I tried using Firebug console too.

Comment: @Musa it is 1 as you can see.

Comment: length on a jquery object is a special property since jQuery always returns an array of objects, sometimes of length 0 if it finds nothing. Length on a regular DOM node is not a valid property. What are you trying to achieve specifically?

Comment: When using jQuery, you check the `.length` of a jQuery object to see whether a selector matched any elements. When using `.getElementById()`, however, you'll get back either an element or `null`.

Comment: What kind of result do you expect from `document.getElementById("user").length`?

Comment: Are you trying to detect if a certain element exists in the DOM?

Comment: @Franco Yes. Btw I found the answer below :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to want to check the element exists.

In the case of a single DOM element (not a collection), there's no need to check the length.

```js
var user = document.getElementById("user");
var divExists = user != null;
alert(divExists);
```

```html
<div id="user"></div>
```

Note: when using a function returning a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), like [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), checking the length might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

`getElementById` returns 1 element (if found) or null, and the `length` property for a Dom element is not defined, that's why you're getting `undefined`.
So you basically just have to check whether the element exists...

```
var user = document.getElementById("user");
if (user) { //... Whatever }
```

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID; the ID is a string which
>   can be used to identify the element; it can be established using the
>   id attribute in HTML, or from script. [...] If there is no element
>   with the given id, this function returns null.

cfr. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById